# how to access array from stringify object

Tags: json

This is the json object created using JSON.stringify()  method.
I am unable to access the data1(array here). how to access and print it.

```
{"data1":[{"text":"TMS-1","id":"1.0","children":[{"text":"Services","id":"1.0.0","children":[{"text":"child service","id":"1.0.0.0"}]},{"text":"Applications","id":"1.0.1","children":[]},{"text":"Radios","id":"1.0.2","children":[{"text":"radio child","id":"1.0.2.0","children":[{"text":"child 2","id":"1.0.2.0.0"},{"text":"child 2.1","id":"1.0.2.0.1"},{"text":"child 2.2","id":"1.0.2.0.2"}]},{"text":"radio service1","id":"1.0.2.1","children":[{"text":"child 1.2.1","id":"1.0.2.0.0"}]}]},{"text":"Platform","id":"1.0.3","children":[{"text":"platform child","id":"1.0.3.0"}]},{"text":"Faults","id":"1.0.4","children":[{"text":"Fault child","id":"1.0.4.0"}]}]}]}
```

Comment: Ream more on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify this function is outputting a string, not array

Comment: Yeah. can we access the array which is in a string? @ZayLau

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var str = JSON.stringify(something); // should be {"data1":[{"text":"TMS-1","id":"1.0","children":[{"text":"Services","id":"1.0.0","children":[{"text":"child service","id":"1.0.0.0"}]},{"text":"Applications","id":"1.0.1","children":[]},{"text":"Radios","id":"1.0.2","children":[{"text":"radio child","id":"1.0.2.0","children":[{"text":"child 2","id":"1.0.2.0.0"},{"text":"child 2.1","id":"1.0.2.0.1"},{"text":"child 2.2","id":"1.0.2.0.2"}]},{"text":"radio service1","id":"1.0.2.1","children":[{"text":"child 1.2.1","id":"1.0.2.0.0"}]}]},{"text":"Platform","id":"1.0.3","children":[{"text":"platform child","id":"1.0.3.0"}]},{"text":"Faults","id":"1.0.4","children":[{"text":"Fault child","id":"1.0.4.0"}]}]}]}
var JsonArray = JSON.parse(str);
```

read more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Answer (score 0):

Implement the following code to get the array.

```
try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(yourResponseString);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data1");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```